# Почему при вводе 3х числовых значений выдает ошибку "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Procent
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double Calculate(string userInput)
        {
            var parts = userInput.Split();
            var cash = double.Parse(parts[0]);
            var rate = double.Parse(parts[1]);
            var month = double.Parse(parts[2]);
            return cash * Math.Pow(1 + (rate / 100) / 12, month);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Calculate(""));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверно, потому что введенное значение нигде вами не используется, а в функцию Calculate вы всегда передаете пустую строку?

Comment: @demonplus А как передать в этот метод значения введенные пользователем с консоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема в том, что в `Calculate()` вы не передаете строку из консоли. Это можно сделать так:

```
string values = Console.ReadLine();
Calculate(values);
```

Конечно, значение, возвращаемое Calculate можно выводить на консоль:

```
 Console.WriteLine(Calculate(values));
```

В идеале еще нужна обработка ошибок, проверка, что строка действительно содержит три числа и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало